# What are the Azure Table Storage Performance Target implications of various kinds of range queries?

Tags: performance, azure, azure-table-storage

This question concerns the Performance Target thresholds in Azure Table Storage that are described [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets/). In particular, I'm concerned about the 2K entities per partition, and 20K entities total, per second, threshold. My understanding is that if you go over these thresholds, Azure may begin to return 500 and 503 errors.

I think I may be running into this, and I'm looking for clarification about exactly how these items are counted. I understand that if you perform scans of either the full table or a partition, you will potentially be "charged" for each entity that Azure scans, regardless of the number you return. Since you could burn your entire query "budget" on a single poorly designed query of a 2000-row table, I want to make sure I correctly understand this.

For the sake of clarity, here's a simple table and same sample data that we can use in the next few scenarios.

```
PartitionKey | RowKey | Name
----------------------------
A              1        Alice
A              2        Bob
A              3        Candice
A              4        Dave
A              5        Eugenia
B              6        Frank
B              7        Genevieve
B              8        Henry
C              9        Ike
C              10       Jennifer
```

For each of the following scenarios, I'll call the amount of entities that are "charged" against the Performance Target "budget" the Performance Charge. Let's start from the most egregious offense and go from there.

**No PK, no RK specified**
Query: Name == "Frank"
Performance Charge: 10 entities

I believe this is correct (please do correct me if I'm wrong). But what about the following scenarios?

**PK specified, no RK specified**
Query: PartitionKey == "A" AND Name == "Frank"
Performance Charge: 5 entities

**PK specified, RK range specified**
Query: PartitionKey == "A" AND (RowKey >= "2" AND RowKey <= "3")
Performance Charge: 2? or 5?

**PK specified, RK partial range specified**
Query: PartitionKey == "A" AND RowKey >= "4"
Performance Charge: 2? or 5?

**PK range specified**
Query: PartitionKey >= "B" AND PartitionKey <= "C"
Performance Charge: 5? or 10?

**Partial PK range specified**
Query: PartitionKey >= "C"
Performance Charge: 2? or 10?

Thank you in advance for any pointers!

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, here is my understanding of your queries, you could refer to it.

> No PK, no RK specified
>   Query: Name == "Frank"

**Full table scan:** Query results in scanning the entire table (i.e. all rows in all partitions in a table).

Performance Charge:10

> PK specified, no RK specified
>   Query: PartitionKey == "A" AND Name == "Frank"
>
> PK specified, RK range specified
>   Query: PartitionKey == "A" AND (RowKey >= "2" AND RowKey <= "3")
>
> PK specified, RK partial range specified
>   Query: PartitionKey == "A" AND RowKey >= "4"

**Row range scan:** Query results in scanning the rows within the specific partition.

Performance Charge:5

> Query: PartitionKey >= "B" AND PartitionKey <= "C"
>
> Query: PartitionKey >= "C"

**Partition range scan:** Query results in scanning a range of partition servers.

Performance Charge:5, 2

In addition, you could follow [Designing a Scalable Partitioning Strategy for Azure Table Storage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh508997.aspx) and this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2010/11/06/how-to-get-most-out-of-windows-azure-tables/#_Queries) for a better understanding of it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm surprised by your second block there. I was under the impression that RowKeys are indexed. Shouldn't that mean that the query that specifies a range of RowKeys (>= "2" AND <= "4") should only cost the time it takes to scan Rows 2, 3, and 4, for a Performance Charge of 3 entities? Thank you for the links as well.